# How to prototype a large linear programming problem in R

Tags: r, linear-programming, operations-research

I've outlined a linear programming problem which has about 15100 variables (unknowns) and 9280 constraints (and all x>=0). About 90% of the constraint matrix would be sparse.  Coding the setup of the real-world problem will take a long time because of the data collection and manipulation challenges.  Before attempting that, I'm experimenting with a prototype.  The purpose of the prototype is to see if my PC can solve a problem of this size in a matter of hours.  The code for the prototype is below. I have several questions:

- Is the prototype reasonable?  It's of the same size and its
  constraint matrix has a sparseness similar to what I envision.
- I've tried three optimization functions: linprog::solveLP;
  RglpK::Rglpk_solve_LP; and Rsymphony::Rsymphony_solve_LP. None has
  solved the problem within 3 hours.  My reading suggests that the
  interior point algorithm is useful in solving large problems with
  sparse matrices. Do any of these functions use this algorithm?  Is
  another package better suited for my problem?
  (I've read [Google's Guide on Advanced LP Solving](https://developers.google.com/optimization/lp/lp_advanced) and     this
  [benchmarking study](http://plato.asu.edu/bench.html) and the helpful [Sandia report Comparison of
  open-source linear programming](https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/1104761/).  From reading these, I would have
  thought 3 hours would be sufficient.  Any rough estimate of the time it should
  require?
- Is there a way to use parallel processing to speed up this problem on
  a Windows machine?

```
nVariables <- 15100
nConstraints <- 9280

cvec <- rep(1, nVariables)
set.seed(101)
coeffs <- runif(runif(nVariables * nConstraints))
coeffs[sample(nVariables * nConstraints, 
              0.9 * nVariables * nConstraints, 
              replace = FALSE)] <- 0

Amat <- matrix(coeffs, nrow = nConstraints, ncol = nVariables)
bvec <- apply(Amat, 1, sum) + 10
rm(coeffs)  

library(Matrix)
sparseAmat <- as(Amat, "sparseMatrix")
save(sparseAmat, bvec, cvec, nVariables, nConstraints, file = "sparsevecs.rdata")

timeLimit <- 1000 * 60 * 60 * 3 # 3 hours in millisecs
library(linprog)
library(R.utils)
print("starting solveLP")
print(Sys.time())
withTimeout(system.time(testSolveLP <- solveLP(cvec, bvec, sparseAmat, maximum = TRUE)), 
            timeout = timeLimit/1000, onTimeout = "warning")
print(Sys.time())

library(Rglpk)
print("starting Rglpk_solve_LP")
print(Sys.time())
testRglpk <- Rglpk_solve_LP(cvec, sparseAmat, dir = rep("<=", nConstraints), rhs = bvec, 
                            max = TRUE,
                            control = list(tm_limit = timeLimit, 
                                           presolve = FALSE, 
                                           vebose = TRUE))
print(Sys.time())

library(Rsymphony)
print("starting Rsymphony")
print(Sys.time())
testRSymphony <- Rsymphony_solve_LP(cvec, sparseAmat, dir = rep("<=", nConstraints), 
                                    rhs = bvec, max = TRUE,
                                    time_limit = timeLimit/1000)
print(Sys.time())
```

Here's the thought behind the code above.  'cvec' is the objective vector and is all ones.  The problem simply maximizes the sum of the values.  The coefficient matrix 'Amat' are random uniform values with 90% replaced by zeros to make it sparse.  The right hand side values ('bvec') are the sum of the values in each row plus 10.  Thus a value of 1 for each variable should meet the condition of each constraint.  Thus the problem is feasible. I used a sparse matrix ('sparseAmat') hoping that would reduce memory and speed the solution. This was after attempting with the base version 'Amat'.

I'm a financial professional familiar with linear programming and R. I'm using Windows 11 with an Intel I-7 1800Mhz, 14 cores, 32GB RAM.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: This is not a very large LP, so a good LP solver (and modeling tool) should handle this quite easily.

Comment: Agree with Erwin.  Your problem with 10% density should not be difficult to solve as an LP.  Note that if the coefficients of your objective function are all ones, the problem could be massively degenerate, so the solver may be stuck generating all of the degenerate solutions.  Suggest generating random objective function coefficients around a range, e.g. runif(151,000, 1, 100)  Also better if you post your exact formulation for review.

Comment: My exact formulation is in the original post. The goal is to verify my PC's capacity to solve a problem of this size before I try to formulate my real-world problem.  I see your point that it could be degenerate.  I have replaced the cvec (objective) coeffs with cvec <- 10 * (seq(from = nVariables, to = 1, by = -1) / nVariables)  so that the coefficients are unique and range from about 10 to 0.  This way I expect the first variables in the solution to have a larger weight.   Is there reason to use random coefficients?  Rerunning with 8 hr limits.

Comment: Re: "Is there reason to use random coefficients?"  Perturbating real coefficients with small epsilon values is a standard method for avoiding degeneracy.  With a toy model, as long as all are different.

Comment: With a commercial LP solver, this takes 109.64sec (barrier, no crossover).

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, here are a couple of benchmarks on the same problem using python's `scipy.optimize` as a modeling framework, which now uses (by default) the (new-ish) open source solver `HiGHS` which has proven pretty decent in my experience.  I'm not a regular user of `scipy.optimize`, but it is very convenient for problems like this that have a natural matrix formulation.

My limited experience in solving large-ish problems that are generated partially or completely from random values/coefficients is that they are quite slow for LP and ILP.  Basically asking the solver to solve "noise" which takes a lot of iterations.  I used a `cvec` that was a random distribution of range [1, `n_var`].  Using a "ones" `cvec` never got too far.  I also tried two flavors of `b_vec`, one as you did, the other random integers, which I think reduced the complexity of the solve significantly, though I didn't poke around too much.

**TL;DR**:  results for problem of same dimensionality & sparsity:

- 198 seconds with a randomized `b_vec`
- 2860 seconds with your `b_vec`

##### Code (`python`):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import linprog
from time import time
n_vars = 15100
A = np.random.random(n_vars * 9280).reshape(9280, n_vars)
A = np.where(np.random.binomial(1, 0.10, A.shape), A, 0)  # <- apply a random mask with 10% density  (A will be 90% sparse)
b_vec = np.random.randint(low=1, high=30, size=A.shape[0])
# b_vec = np.sum(A, axis=1) + 10

tic = time()
cvec = np.random.randint(low=1, high=n_vars, size=A.shape[1]) * -1
# cvec = np.ones(n_vars) * -1
res = linprog(cvec, A_ub=A, b_ub=b_vec)
toc = time()

print(res.message)
print(f'time: {toc-tic:0.2f}')
print(res.x[:20])
print(max(res.x))
```

##### Results (random `b_vec`):

```
Optimization terminated successfully. (HiGHS Status 7: Optimal)
time: 198.71
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
0.4854054502299248
[Finished in 203.3s]
```

##### Results (your `b_vec`):

```
Optimization terminated successfully. (HiGHS Status 7: Optimal)
time: 2859.69
[0.         0.         0.         4.21892154 0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.         0.        ]
27.0425384080877
[Finished in 2864.3s]
```